# Accessing the GSM modem on a linux mobile (eg. N900)

Tags: linux, mobile, modem, gsm, maemo

I'm trying to access the GSM modem of a mobile set, so I can send AT commands to it. Instead of programming, I tried to have a test run using `minicom` on the phone. The problem is I cannot find the device I should connect to, I tried /dev/tty0 tty1 and also ttyS0 and alike, but none of them responded to my `AT` command.

So what should I do? Is it even possible?

**Platform**: Nokia N900 (running maemo linux)

Comment: I've somehow figured that I should use pnatd/phonet to connect to the underlying modem and send AT commands.

But the daemon is not running on the phone, and is not present in init.d folder (though it's accessible as a standalone app)

How can I connect to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was solved when I ran:

`pnatd /dev/tty`

just that simple, though not documented well anywhere, I think.